# HTML FireFox Bookmarks

Tags: python, html, internet-explorer, firefox, bookmarks

So i Have a pythons script that is outputting firefox bookmarks. (don't ask):
The bookmark folders are displaying correctly, but no bookmarks inside.
I keep comparing it against a working firefox html export, and can't seem to find a difference. Most likely just need a fresh pair of eyes on this.

Oh and the real ip's and names were hidden for confidential reasons.

This is the outputted html:
http://pastebin.com/VKZukgkJ

THis is a working Untouched firefox export(the one I was comparing it to):
http://pastebin.com/24gQ9ii7

Comment: post your python script so we can read that too.

Comment: Did you try using a diff tool to check the two files?

Comment: there not exact copies. Such as if you look at a firefox output it has extra data, such as date added, icon data etc. But the core format appears to be the same to me, which is what is making me sit here scratching my head.

Comment: Also If we can find the error in my html, I can fix it in the python script myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links in the example are full URLs (meaning they include the protocol).
Your example does not seem to include the protocol, so that may be the issue.

Comment: I'll be.... That was it... Thanks so much. Glad I posted this, sometimes the most simple things can be overlooked.